# Isomorphism of Non-Symmetric Matrix when Permutation-Set is given: A simple observation

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, proof-verification, permutations, graph-isomorphism

**Context:**
Consider, two  $m \times n$ matrices $A, B$ such that  there is a permutation $\kappa$ that  such that such that $A^{\kappa}=B$  *(Wielandt's notation)*, i.e. $A, B$ are *isomorphic* but not equal.

Since, permutations of rows are independent of   permutations of columns, so $\kappa = \sigma \pi$ where $\sigma$ is a row permutation that acts on rows of non-symmetric matrix and $\pi$ acts on columns of matrix.

A set of column-permutations $\beta_k$  is a subset of the set of  all possible permutations of columns of $A$. So, $\beta_k \subset S_n$.

A set of column-permutations $\gamma_k$  is a subset of the set of  all possible permutations of columns of $B$. So, $\gamma_k \subset S_n$.

We consider 2 different set due to different labeling of columns in $A, B$ .

$\pi$ is in the set $\beta_k, \gamma_k$  but with different label.

This is equivalent to *bipartite graph isomorphism.*

$\textit{Unique Column :}$  If in a matrix, there exists  one  column which has no similar column   in that matrix, regardless any row  permutation , then that column is an Unique Column.

$\textit{Example:}$ In the  matrix $ \mathcal{A}$, $2^{nd}$  column  is  unique. In the $ \mathcal{B}$, all three columns  are unique.
$$\mathcal{A}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{array} \right) ,
 \mathcal{B}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\ \end{array} \right) $$

**Obseravation:**

Though **we have different labeling for $\pi$ in $\beta_k, \gamma_k$**, $\pi$ in $\beta_k$  will change the position of some unique columns of $A$ to the same position exactly as  $\pi$ in $\gamma_k$  will do in $B$.

For example,if $\pi$ in $\beta_k$   changes  the column of $1^{st}$  position  to the  column of $6^{th}$  positionof $A$   then   $\pi$ in $\gamma_k$  will change  the column of $1^{st}$  position  to the  column of $6^{th}$  position  in $B$.

Thus we can find/distinguish  $\pi$  or an automorphism of $A^{\pi}$in both $\beta_k, \gamma_k$.

**Question:**

*Is this observation correct all the time? Is there an exception?*